# Source a PowerShell script on each new shell

Tags: powershell

I have a script called Restart-Audio.ps1

```
Stop-Process -Confirm -Name musicapp*
Stop-Service audiosrv
Stop-Service AudioEndpointBuilder
Start-Service audiosrv
Invoke-Item C:\path\to\music\app.exe
```

Every time I start a new PowerShell session, I want this script to run when I type "Restart-Audio" like a normal cmdlet. When I tried to add this to my PowerShell profile, it tried to run the script, asking for the confirmation to stop the processes. I don't want it to run as soon as a PowerShell session starts; I want the command to run when I tell it to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using Powershell profiles, see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/%5Clibrary/Bb613488(v=VS.85).aspx) for details.

You basically create (if the file doesn't already exist) `C:\Users\<<UserName>>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` and that can contain your above script.

I'd construct the file as:

```
Function Restart-Audio{
Stop-Process -Confirm -Name musicapp*
Stop-Service audiosrv
Stop-Service AudioEndpointBuilder
Start-Service audiosrv
Invoke-Item C:\path\to\music\app.exe
}
```

Then you just open Powershell and type `Restart-Audio` to run that function.

Additionally, if you save the script to any folder in your `$env:PATH` you can just type the first few characters of the script name and TAB complete to run the script.